# Find all filename that contains a particular substring in them

Tags: unix, grep, find

I wanted to write a command that would help me fetch recursively in a folder all filenames that have a particular text in them . Suppose my folder contains lot of files two of them being `largest_pallindrome_subsequence_1.cpp` and `largest_pallindrome_subsequence_2.cpp` . Now I want to find files which have `sub` in it . So the search should return me these 2 cpp files as mentioned above.
The thing is that I also want to look for a file with particular extension say `.txt` or `.cpp` .

I tried using `grep --include=\*{.cpp} -rnw . -e "sub"` but this doesnot work for me.

Comment: What are those `{}` doing in that include argument?

Comment: Are you looking for  files that contain that string in the filename, or in the file contents?

Comment: I am looking for filename and not the string in file contents

Comment: {} just so i can include more extension say in case i want to search for .cpp and also .h file

Comment: You can't use `{}` as a shell expansion without a comma or they stay literal (try `echo {foo,bar}` versus `echo {foo}`). Does that command work without them?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
find ./ -name "*sub*"
```

or:

```
find ./ | grep "sub"
```

Comment: How do i get a filename of a particular extension here ? say .cpp or .txt or .h

Comment: @Invictus With `find . -name "*sub*.cpp"`, and then spending some time reading up on shell globbing patterns...

Comment: When you want both `mysub.xxx` and `different.cpp`, use `egrep "sub|.cpp"`

Comment: No, just use `-o` for "or": `find . \( -name '*sub*.cpp' -o -name '*.cpp' \)`